# Definite Integrals (Fundamental Theorem of Calculus Part 1)

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Let 
$$
F(x) = \int_{x^2}^{\ln x}\frac{\mathrm{e}^s}{s^2+1}ds, \qquad x>0.
$$
Find $F'(x)$ for all $x>0$.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this one? What have you done so far?

Answer (score 1):

The integrand function $\;\frac{e^s}{s^2+1}\;$ is defined and continuous in the whole real line, and thus by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

$$\int_a^b\frac{e^s}{s^2+1} ds=G(b)-G(a)\;,\;\;\text{with the primitive}$\;\;G'(s)=\frac{e^s}{s^2+1}$$

Well, now apply this in your case:

$$\int_{x^2}^{\log x}\frac{e^s}{s^2+1}ds=G(\log x)-G(x^2)$$

and now differentiate... **and remember the Chain rule** .